# Update the Suite Name at RunTime

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

Is there any workaround to set the SuiteName at the time of test execution,
 same as we can achieve for Test Name using ITest Interface.

Answer (score 1):

This works perhaps. I have not tested it yet.

`Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestClass().getXmlClass().setName("NewName");`